# Search for existing Users in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have a `User` Entity class that looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Index
    private String username;
    private Long dateOfBirth;
    // More fields...
}
```

I would like to create an API method that searches datastore for all `User` entities that more or less match the search text and return a list of possible results. For example;

```
public CollectionResponse<User> searchForUser(@Named("text") searchText searchText) {
    // Some code here.
}
```

This API method will be used in an Android app where a user types in a username one character at a time. Each time a character is typed I will have the `searchForUser()` method run with what they have typed so far and return the list of possible suggestions.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get started on such a method if you have done it before? Thanks.

Comment: Bad idea. You will expose all usernames to anyone who is not even a registered user in your app.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I didn't bother putting it into the question, but I have additional parameters that ensure only registered users are allowed to call the said method (and all methods in my API). Thank you for your concern though!

Comment: You should not display usernames to registered users either. (1) It weakens security. (2) It weakens user privacy.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Then why does Instagram, Facebook, etc. allow you to do that..? How the heck else are you supposed to friend new users???

Comment: Usually by name or email address. Usernames must be unique, so users are often forced to choose usernames like andrei123 which makes it impossible for another user to tell who this really is. Anyway, it's your choice.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Thanks for the suggestion but my model more closely resembles Instagram, Snapchat, etc, where people know each other by usernames.

Comment: It may be a little slow for a mobile device - users typically type faster than your API will respond. This may create some issues when your API returns results for "a" by the time a user already typed "andrei".

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Well what you do is wait maybe .5 ~ 1 seconds after a user stops typing and then you go ahead and make the network call to run the API method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your use case, you will always return a number of results up to a certain limit (e.g. 5). Thus, you can run a standard query with an inequality filter on username property and set a limit on the number of results returned. Make sure you add a sort order on username.

For example, if a user typed "an", you will search for all entities with username >= "an".

When you get your results back, remove those that do not start with the user input. For example,

```
andre - add to response

andrei - add to response

boris - do not add and stop - all subsequent entries won't match
```

Now you know that only two results matched user input.

Comment: How does the `username >= "an"` inequality filter exactly work? How does it exactly match... do you know?

Comment: It works like any other filter on an indexed property which is sorted. "a" will be before "b", etc.

Comment: You can improve this somewhat with a second inequality filter. From the Objectify FAQ: `ofy().load().type(MyEntity.class).filter("field >=", start).filter("field <", start + "\uFFFD");`

Comment: One other thing I should mention just in case: This is an eventually consistent query. While great for letting people lookup other usernames, filtering cannot be used to enforce uniqueness of usernames when people are signing up.